# Mocking @material-ui/pickers in Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, material-ui

Edit: [Non working repo with slightly different approach](https://github.com/mark-buhagiar/Material-UI-Mocking/)

I need to mock out the material UI date pickers for my tests (working under the assumption that they have their own tests so I shouldn't need to test that). I managed to get this up and running when having a mock inside my test file as per the below:

```
 jest.mock('@material-ui/pickers', () => {
     const actual = jest.requireActual('@material-ui/pickers');

     return {
         ...actual,
         DatePicker: (() => (props: any): JSX.Element => {
             return (
                 <input
                     data-testid="mockedDateField"
                     onChange={(e): void => {
                         props.onChange(e.target.value);
                     }}
                 />
             );
         })(),
     };
 });
```

However I want to move this to the `__mocks__` folder such that I don't have to repeat the code block above in all my test suites. The `__mocks__` folder is a sibling of `node_modules`.

To this end, I created `__mocks__\@material-ui\pickers\index.js` with the following block:

```
import React from 'react';

const actual = jest.requireActual('@material-ui/pickers');

const mockMaterialUiPickers = {
    ...actual,
    DatePicker: () => (props) => {
        return (
            <input
                data-testid="mockedDateField"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    props.onChange(e.target.value);
                }}
            />
        );
    },
};

export default mockMaterialUiPickers;
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like this is being picked up properly.
I have added `jest.mock('@material-ui/pickers')` to my `test` file.
This is then imported in my components using the following

```
import { DatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';
```

I am assuming that my problem is with the path  of my mocks, however i am unable to figure out what the correct one is!

Thanks in advance.

[image: __mocks__ folder structure]

[image: Node modules structure for @materials-ui]

Answer (score 1):

From what I read [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules), you have to name your mock file `__mocks__\@material-ui\pickers.js`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, creating `src/__mocks__/@material-ui/pickers.tsx`file with the implementation below did the trick (I'm using TypeScript, but I assume JavaScript implementation would be similar):

```
import React from 'react';
import { DatePickerProps } from '@material-ui/pickers';

const actual = jest.requireActual('@material-ui/pickers');

export const MuiPickersUtilsProvider = actual.MuiPickersUtilsProvider;

export const DatePicker = (props: DatePickerProps) => (
  <input
    data-testid="mockedDateField"
    onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      props.onChange(e.target.value);
    }}
  />
);
```